# Return common elements of arrays in result set - PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have table foo(id INTEGER, values VARCHAR[]):

```
Id / Values
1  / A,B,C
2  / A,C
```

I would like to write query which returns only elements in values array common for all records.

So for above I would like to get A, C

Any ides? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I found solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37716219/postgres-overlap-arrays-from-one-column

Answer (score 2):

```
with t (id, values) as ( values
    (1, '{A,B,C}'::varchar[]),
    (2, '{A,C}')
)
select v
from
    t
    cross join lateral
    unnest(values) v(v)
group by v
having count(*) = (select count(*) from t)
;
 v 
---
 C
 A
```

Comment: Was about to post similar thing :) For the note: you don't need `cross join` using `lateral`. Simple `SELECT v FROM t, LATERAL unnest(values) v(v) GROUP BY v.v HAVING count( v.v ) > 1` would do the same :)

Comment: @KristoMägi I think it is clearer to explicit the `cross join`

Comment: Understand the clearer part, but query plan looks better without cross join solution ;) But if there are not much of data to go over then it doesn't matter – just little optimization trick :)

Comment: @KristoMägi You mean you generated enough data to analize different query plans?

Comment: I did generate randomly ~60K records but must correct myself that the planner diff wasn't because of the cross join lateral vs simply lateral. The difference is in the `HAVING` clause. In your example the `count(*) = (select count(*) from t)` requires additional scan over data set and due to that duplicates buffer shared hit than using `count( v.v. ) > 1` comparison :) Other than actually wasn't difference, so it is a matter of likeability of syntax/writing style :)