# Array overlap count

Tags: arrays, postgresql, count, overlap

How can I calculate the overlap count between an array passed as argument and a column of type array.

```
 SELECT id1, overlap_count(ary, '{32,56,72,...,996}') FROM tbl
```

where it checks the ary field for how many of the elements match with the array passed as argument.

My question is two fold. My table is something like this :   ID1,ID2,ary
I want to use multidimensional arrays if possible (where every array can be any dimensions), but suspect it would be more complex or very slow.

if not I would have to use duplicate records with one-dim array, like this :

```
  | ID1  | ID2 |  ary   |
  | 5    | 7   |  {...} |
  | 43   | 611 |  {...} |
  | 5    | 7   |  {...} |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple function for the job.

```sql
create or replace function overlap_count(arr_a integer[], arr_b integer[]) 
returns integer language sql immutable as
$$
 select count(*)::integer from unnest(arr_a) a inner join unnest(arr_b) b on a = b;
$$;
```